# cmd command to format hard drive in 5 hours

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

Is there any windows cmd command to start formatting a hard drive in an allocated time for windows 10?

i.e run the cmd, then the hard drive starts reformatting in 5 hours?

Comment: Is there a a reason you can't use the Task Scheduler for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `SLEEP` first:

```
SLEEP 18000 & YOUR-FORMAT-COMMAND
```

Comment: Sleep is no longer in Win10 except resource pack..... Use timeout instead....